# set log level log4j externally

Tags: java, log4j, salesforce, spring-batch

I have made a goof up. I set log level for log4j in its property file to test it in my local machine but we give log level from outside in shell script or property file when we deploy it on server and we bundle log4j.property file in jar itself(I know it's kind of weird practice but I cant do anything about it now) . For that we comment the log.level line from log4j.properties file and read log level from VM arguments. Now the problem is that I missed to comment the log.level line which was set to DEBUG level and I want logs for Support team which has to be at INFO level. Now even if I am trying to pass log.level externally, the property file in overriding the value. what can I do about it now? The code is set to run in production this weekend so I cannot touch it. Please save me  :)

Comment: It may be possible via JMX

Answer (score 0):

You can start the application with `-Dlog4j.configuration=/your/config.properties` to override the configuration which is picked from the classpath.